# iOS Xamarin: Attach Photo to Email Body

Tags: ios, xamarin, photo, email-attachments

I am building an app, that allows user to take a picture, extract meta data and attach photo to Email + meta data information.

However the issue is that If you capture a photo from camera, the event does not return a ReferenceUrl, atleast I dont see one. I do get some form of URL but that doesn't work as intended. Here is my code:-

```
 // Take a photo with the Camera //
 partial void BtnCamera_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
        {
            UIImagePickerController imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController();
            imagePicker.PrefersStatusBarHidden();
            imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;

            // handle saving picture and extracting meta-data from picture //
            imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += Handle_FinishedPickingMedia;

            // present //
            PresentViewController(imagePicker, true, () => { });

        }
```

To save the image I call the SaveImageToPhone() from my FinishedPickingMedia handler. It looks like this:-

```
private static void SaveImagetoPhone(UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
{
    NSUrl url = null;
    void ImageData(PHAsset asset)
    {
        if (asset == null)
            throw new Exception("PHAsset is null");
        //PHImageManager.DefaultManager.RequestImageData(asset, null, (data, dataUti, orientation, info) =>
        //    {

        //        var urlX = info.ValueForKey(new NSString("PHImageFileURLKey"));
        //        url = info.ValueForKey(new NSString("PHImageFileURLKey")) as NSUrl;
        //        DataClass._fileURL = urlX.ToString();
        //    });
    }
    PHAsset phAsset;
    if (e.ReferenceUrl == null)
    {
        e.OriginalImage?.SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) =>
        {
            if (error == null)
            {
                var options = new PHFetchOptions
                {
                    FetchLimit = 1,
                    SortDescriptors = new[] { new NSSortDescriptor("creationDate", true) }
                };
                phAsset = PHAsset.FetchAssets(options).LastOrDefault() as PHAsset;
                ImageData(phAsset);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        phAsset = PHAsset.FetchAssets(new[] { e.ReferenceUrl }, null).FirstOrDefault() as PHAsset;
        ImageData(phAsset);
    }
}
```

In this function I have a couple of lines commented out, it is here where I was trying to get the reference URL for the Photo (unsuccessfully).

And finally my email () looks like this:-

```
  partial void BtnMessageDone_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
        {
            MFMailComposeViewController mailController;
            if (MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail)
            {
                StringBuilder htmlBodyMail = FormatEmailBody();
                mailController = new MFMailComposeViewController();
                // do mail operations here
                mailController.SetToRecipients(new string[] { "xxyyzz@...com" });
                mailController.SetSubject("mail test");
                mailController.SetMessageBody(htmlBodyMail.ToString(), false);


                UIImage img = UIImage.FromFile(DataClass._fileURL);
                mailController.AddAttachmentData(img.AsJPEG(), "image/JPG", "Image.JPG");
                mailController.Finished += (object s, MFComposeResultEventArgs args) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(args.Result.ToString());
                    args.Controller.DismissViewController(true, null);
                };
                this.PresentViewController(mailController, true, null);
            }
```

Does anyone have any pointers on how to get the absolute path/reference URL of the photo taken by the in app camera and attach it to the email body ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Path property on the NSUrl class:

```
NSString urlString = new NSString("file:///stack/over%20flow/foobar.txt");
NSUrl myFileUrl = new NSUrl (urlString);
Console.WriteLine (myFileUrl.AbsoluteString);
string absPath = myFileUrl.Path;
Console.WriteLine (absPath);
```

Comment: So I was trying this:  url = info.ValueForKey(new NSString("PHImageFileURLKey")) as NSUrl;
DataClass._fileURL = urlX.ToString();

Comment: should I just add the url.Path ?

Comment: Yes, that is what you need.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get Null exception even though the file path is displayed as: "/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0036.JPG"